# no jquery background: -webkit-canvas(?) with a java script that doesn't contain ".getCSSCanvasContext" but ".getContext('2d'); instead

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I do not want to use jquery on this project. I've solved this problem for FireFox using "background: -moz-element(#niose)" but "background: -webkit-canvas(niose);" doesn't work the javascript contains

```
canvas = document.getElementById("niose");
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

not

```
ctx = document.getCSSCanvasContext("2d", "niose", 170, 9);
```

How do I use "background:-webkit-canvas(?);" with this script?  The canvas is an animation so I don't want to use "Canvas.toDataURL("image/png")"
andding these lines after rendering the canvas

```
var ctx = document.getCSSCanvasContext('2d','niose',170,90);
ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
```

works for "background: -webkit-canvas(niose);" but then "background: -moz-element(#niose)" doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by adding

```
   var ctx = document.getCSSCanvasContext('2d','niose',170,90);
   ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
```

after rendering lines but at the start of loop